# How to continuously sync a folder between two Ubuntu servers?

Tags: sync, rsync, mirrors

I have two servers which are going to host two instances of a load-balanced app. Users can upload photos to `/photos` folder on either of the servers.

So the question is how to sync the two servers so that both of the folders are always up to date for the users?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look into GlusterFS.

GlusterFS is a distributed system, that allows data to live in many places. The file system handles synchronization. In essence what you want appears to be a replicated Gluster file system with two bricks. When you need to scale, you can simply add bricks to your Gluster environment.

In addition, Gluster has some neat features, so if you for performance reasons need more servers, you can specify that all data should be written to at least two places, but not more. The data will be available everywhere the GlusterFS is mounted.

[image: Taken from Gluster's documentation]

Instead of describing the various modes of Gluster, I [suggest that you have a look at the Architecture description they provide](https://docs.gluster.org/en/latest/Quick-Start-Guide/Architecture/), which has some information on how to configure it.